# MongoDB geo index not working on production server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Just moved to a production Ubuntu instance and I'm getting:

```
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query, name=MongoError, ok=0, errmsg=error processing query: ns=esper.usersTree: $and
gender $eq "female"
profileSetup $eq true
age $lt 25
age $gt 21
$not
    _id $eq ObjectId('5b248a699dc80c04b112a289')
GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=10000 isNearSphere=0
```

However, the index has been configured:

[image]

Tried restarting MongoDB. Is there some sort of cache or command that needs to run to configure the indexes?

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: The same query works locally

Comment: You should post your query too

Comment: Your query is on a different namespace (`esper.users`) than the output you've provided for `getIndexes()` (which uses `test.users`). If you change to the same database (`use esper`) I suspect you'll find the geo index hasn't been created there.

Comment: -_- Thanks Stennie post as an answer so I can mark as accepted